# Making rounded, coloured columns the same height

Tags: html, css

I'm experiencing the perennial problem of getting two columns with content of an uneven height to fill their parent container and be the same length independent of their content which will vary. I'm aware of some of the hacks for this such as using a vertically tiled background image on the parent object to simulate the columns but I also want rounded corners on the columns as well as them being different colours.

The height of the parent object is dictated by the height of the tallest 'child' column which is fine but the vertically smaller column's background shrinks to the size of its content making its background shorter than the background container. In this example I've coloured the usually invisible background object black for visibility and want the larger blue column on the left to fill this area vertically. In the case of the Blue column being taller, I want the inverse to happen and the yellow column to fill the black parent object.

I've simplified the layout to its simplest form to demonstrate the problem and the code and an image follow.

[image: Uneven column woes]

CSS:

```
html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px; 
    background-color: rgb(0,50,130);
    position: relative;
}

* {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 1em;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
    padding: 0px;
}

/*auto-centering outer container box*/
.outer {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 960px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}

.top {
    width: 960px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
    border-radius: 6px;
}

.mid {
    width: 960px;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 35px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
}

.midmain {
    width: 710px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
    float: left;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

.midside {
    width: 180px;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: rgb(255,225,0);
    float:right;
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

/*Text rules for midside*/
.nav {
width: 180px;
}

.nav a, nav a:link{
 display: block;
 width: 178px;
 height: 28px;
 background-color: blue;
 border: 1px solid rgb(0,20,100);
 padding: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
 margin-top: 0px;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 border-radius: 6px;
 text-align: center;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: white;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
color: black;
background-color: white;
border: 1px solid rgb(128,0,0);
margin-top: -2px;
margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.bot {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,0,0.5);
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px 3px rgba(0,20,60,0.3);
}
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Columns</title>
    <link href="styles/col.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
            <div class="outer">
                <div class="top">

                </div>
                <div class="mid">          
                    <div class="midmain">
                        Main content Main content Main content Main content
                        Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content
                        Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content
                        Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content Main content 
                    </div>
                    <div class="midside">
                        <div class="nav">
                            <a href="/home.aspx">Home</a>
                            <a href="/news.aspx">News</a>
                            <a href="/edu.aspx">Contact</a>
                            <a href="/board.aspx">About</a>
                            <a href="/staff.aspx">Staff</a>
                            <a href="/hist.aspx">Gallery</a>
                            <a href="/sport.aspx">Video</a>
                            <a href="/footy.aspx">Links</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any advice or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Kw

Comment: you want the blue section and the yellow-nav section to be the same height?

Comment: Go look into flexbox.

Comment: How about using javascript?  Get the height of the two boxes, then set both to the height of the taller.

Comment: I'd rather not use JS, but it looks like that or PHP might be the only solution. Flexbox is much less compatible than most of CSS, so again I'd like to avoid relying on that element.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following definitions in your css:

```
.mid {
    width: 960px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 35px;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    position:relative;
}

.midmain {
    position:absolute;
    width: 710px;
    min-height: calc(100% - 50px);
    background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
    margin-right: 6px;
}

.midside {
    width: 180px;
    float:right;
    background-color: rgb(255,225,0);
    border-radius: 6px;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
```

With absolute positioning, the child element's height is defined relative to its parent.

If you're not keen on the `min-height: calc(100% - 50px);`style, you can use the following in its place. It will have the same effect:

```
top:0;
bottom:0;
```

Comment: Tried this but if the content of the blue column is large it overflows the boundaries of the column.

Comment: If you want a scrollbar to appear, add overflow-y:scroll to .midmain. Or, for the whole .mid div to grow in height, try applying the absolute styling to .midside. In either case, it's a separate dimension to the problem.

Comment: Why is the seemingly arbitrary 88% used and not 100%?

Comment: @Kwangle, because the div has padding which would make the overall size > 100%. You can use top:0; bottom:0; instead.

Comment: you need to use `calc` (ie - `height: calc(100% - 40px);`  - this uses the padding amount. Also `float` does nothing in this aspect when you're using `position: absolute`, fyi. @Kwangle - add `box-sizing:border-box;` so when you're using width/height calculations it takes into account the padding, margin, etc

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I've tried everything that has been suggested but can't get this to work. The content on the pages can vary greatly so I need something that can react to the sizes, but I'm starting to think this can't be done with pure CSS, so maybe JS is the way to go.

Comment: Try changing using min-height: calc(100% - 50px); instead of height. That should get you somewhere closer (see my edit above).

Comment: The box-sizing method is certainly useful, so thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this situation as well sometimes. Basically run this against the elements that you wish to find the tallest (height), and apply that css to the other element(s).

Please note that you need (and should always) apply `box-sizing:border-box;` to all your elements, (ie - `* { box-sizing:border-box;}`

[Fiddle for you](http://jsfiddle.net/bf2djv8s/)

```
var heights = $(".mid > div").map(function ()
    {
        return $(this).outerHeight();
    }).get(),

    maxHeight = Math.max.apply(null, heights);
console.log(maxHeight);

$('.mid > div').css('height',maxHeight);
```

Also note that you should remove the `height` from your (2) div elements (since it's going to be overridden. Keep in mind as well that you "may" want to put this function in a `$(window).resize()` if you're doing responsive (which you should also), and you have media queries that change `padding`, etc.